# Jtable shows "old" text even though render-component has no text anymore

Tags: java, swing, jtable, repaint

i use Jpanel with a Jlabel on it as render-component in my jtable. i add "fake-entries" (=JLabel without text) if there are not enough entries to fill the whole table.
it happens from time to time that text is displayed in the jtable after deleting it. each entrie contains the text of the last table entrie (before the delete) e.g. "Gegeben Bar..." 
Even calling a repaint doesn't solve the problem. Only after inserting a new row the table gets displayed correctly. jre is 1.4_09 on running on linux

here's what i do after clearing table-elements

```
model.fireTableRowsDeleted( firstRow, firstRow + rowCount - 1);
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

i've a function to log the table elements and component when the problem occures

```
     for(int i=0; i < model.getRowCount();i++){
        try
        {
            bw.newLine();
         bw.write("el"+i+" "+model.getValueAt(i, 1)+"->" +model.getValueAt(i, 1).hashCode());
         bw.newLine();
         bw.write(" ->"+((JPanel)renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(this, model.getValueAt(i,1),false, false, i, 0)).getComponent(0).hashCode()+"->" +((JPanel)renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(this, model.getValueAt(i,1),false, false, i, 0)).getComponent(0));
         bw.newLine();
         if(observedElement.getElements().size()>i)
             bw.write(" -> "+observedElement.getElements().get(i));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

in the output you can see the neither the element nor the jlabel contain text

```
el0 ->5840819
 ->20546691->javax.swing.JLabel[,4,0,273x19,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=null,border=,flags=8,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEFT,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=<html><font face="Inconsolata,Inconsolata"></font></html>,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
 -> 
el1 ->5840819
 ->20546691->javax.swing.JLabel[,4,0,273x19,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=null,border=,flags=8,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEFT,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=<html><font face="Inconsolata,Inconsolata"></font></html>,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
 -> 
el2 ->5840819
 ->20546691->javax.swing.JLabel[,4,0,273x19,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=null,border=,flags=8,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEFT,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=<html><font face="Inconsolata,Inconsolata"></font></html>,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
 -> 
...
```

any idea what might be the cause of the problem or how to solve it?

Comment: model.fireTableDataChanged(); should be enough. It would make fireTableRowsDeleted redundant. Remove fireTableRowsDeleted and see what happens.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: **don't** call any of the fireXX methods from outside the tableModel - it's the model's inherent responibility to notify its listeners on change.

Comment: @AndrewThompson still that long McDisposal acronym? Doesn't fit into my memory ;-)